Merge discrete integer intervals
What it does
The code starts with a set of integer intervals, and can add new intervals (possibly by updating existing intervals). Essentially, it is a bit array whose index starts at min(interval_start) and ends at max(interval_end).

add adds a new interval into the set, possibly merging with existing intervals
getIntervals gets the intervals that are covered by the given intervals
getMissing gets the intervals that are not covered by the given intervals

Here it is demonstrated visually:
Example
The initial intervals are [[1, 3], [6, 6], [8, 9]]. That is, the bit array from elements 1 to 3, 6 to 6, and 8 to 9 are filled.
[[1, 3], [6, 6], [8, 9]] = |x|x|x| | |x| |x|x| = [[1, 3], [6, 6], [8, 9]]
                            1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

new Intervals([[1, 3], [6, 6], [8, 9]]).getIntervals() === [[1, 3], [6, 6], [8, 9]]
new Intervals([[1, 3], [6, 6], [8, 9]]).getMissing() === [[4, 5], [7, 7]]

At this point, if we add [4, 5] or [2, 6], we get [[1, 6], [8, 9]]:
[[1, 3], [6, 6], [8, 9], [2, 6]] = |x|x|x|x|x|x| |x|x| = [[1, 6], [8, 9]]
                                    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

new Intervals([[1, 3], [6, 6], [8, 9]]).add([2, 6]).getIntervals() === [[1, 6], [8, 9]]
new Intervals([[1, 3], [6, 6], [8, 9]]).add([2, 6]).getMissing() === [[7, 7]]

Additional test cases are provided at the end of the code.
The code
How can I improve the algorithm, or make it more readable? particularly the add method as it contains the bulk of the logic.
class Intervals {
  constructor(initialIntervals = []) {
    this.intervals = [];

    for (const initialInterval of initialIntervals) {
      this.add(initialInterval);
    }
  }

  add(newInterval) {
    if (newInterval.length !== 2) {
      throw ValueError("interval must be [min, max]");
    }

    if (newInterval[0] > newInterval[1]) {
      newInterval.reverse();
    }

    const intervals = [];

    if (this.intervals.length === 0) {
      this.intervals = [newInterval];
      return this;
    }

    // add disjoint interval (beginning)
    if (this.intervals.at(0) && newInterval[1] < this.intervals.at(0)[0] - 1) {
      intervals.push(newInterval);
    }

    let nextNewInterval = null;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.intervals.length; i++) {
      const interval = this.intervals[i];

      if (nextNewInterval !== null && interval[0] > nextNewInterval[1] + 1) {
        intervals.push(nextNewInterval);
        nextNewInterval = null;
      }

      // add disjoint interval (middle)
      if (
        i > 0 &&
        newInterval[0] > this.intervals[i - 1][1] + 1 &&
        newInterval[1] < this.intervals[i][0] - 1
      ) {
        intervals.push(newInterval);
      }

      if (nextNewInterval === null) {
        nextNewInterval = interval;
      }

      if (newInterval[0] < nextNewInterval[0] - 1) {
        /*
         * |-----|
         *        |-----|
         *
         * or
         *
         * |-----|
         *    |-----|
         *
         * or
         *
         * |----------|
         *    |-----|
         */
        if (newInterval[1] >= nextNewInterval[0] - 1) {
          nextNewInterval = [
            newInterval[0],
            Math.max(newInterval[1], nextNewInterval[1]),
          ];
        }
        /*
         *    |-----|
         * |-----|
         */
      } else if (
        newInterval[0] >= nextNewInterval[0] - 1 &&
        newInterval[0] <= nextNewInterval[1] + 1
      ) {
        nextNewInterval = [
          Math.min(newInterval[0], nextNewInterval[0]),
          Math.max(newInterval[1], nextNewInterval[1], interval[1]),
        ];
        /*
         *          |-----|
         * |-----|
         */
      }
    }

    if (nextNewInterval !== null) {
      intervals.push(nextNewInterval);
      nextNewInterval = null;
    }

    // add disjoint interval (end)
    if (
      this.intervals.at(-1) &&
      newInterval[0] > this.intervals.at(-1)[1] + 1
    ) {
      intervals.push(newInterval);
    }

    this.intervals = intervals;

    return this;
  }

  getIntervals() {
    return this.intervals;
  }

  getMissing() {
    const missing = [];

    for (let i = 1; i < this.intervals.length; i++) {
      const prevInterval = this.intervals[i - 1];
      const currInterval = this.intervals[i];

      missing.push([prevInterval[1] + 1, currInterval[0] - 1]);
    }

    return missing;
  }
}

function check(
  message,
  intervals,
  expectedIntervals,
  checker = (obj) => obj.getIntervals(),
) {
  const expected = JSON.stringify(expectedIntervals);
  const actual = JSON.stringify(checker(intervals));

  if (expected === actual) {
    console.log(`PASSED: ${message}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`FAILED: ${message} (expected ${expected}, got ${actual})`);
  }
}

check(
  "sorted initial intervals",
  new Intervals([
    [6, 10],
    [1, 4],
  ]),
  [
    [1, 4],
    [6, 10],
  ],
);
check(
  "merged initial intervals",
  new Intervals([
    [6, 10],
    [1, 5],
  ]),
  [[1, 10]],
);
check("empty", new Intervals(), []);
check("empty add", new Intervals().add([0, 10]), [[0, 10]]);
check("initial intervals", new Intervals([[12, 15]]), [[12, 15]]);
check("add before", new Intervals([[5, 10]]).add([0, 4]), [[0, 10]]);
check(
  "add before (one less than start)",
  new Intervals([[5, 10]]).add([4, 12]),
  [[4, 12]],
);
check("add between", new Intervals([[0, 10]]).add([6, 12]), [[0, 12]]);
check("add after", new Intervals([[0, 4]]).add([5, 10]), [[0, 10]]);
check(
  "add merged (inside)",
  new Intervals([
    [0, 4],
    [6, 6],
    [8, 10],
  ]).add([5, 7]),
  [[0, 10]],
);
check(
  "add merged (outside)",
  new Intervals([
    [3, 4],
    [6, 6],
    [8, 10],
  ]).add([0, 10]),
  [[0, 10]],
);
check("add disjoint (beginning)", new Intervals([[8, 10]]).add([0, 4]), [
  [0, 4],
  [8, 10],
]);
check(
  "add disjoint (middle)",
  new Intervals([
    [0, 4],
    [8, 10],
  ]).add([6, 6]),
  [
    [0, 4],
    [6, 6],
    [8, 10],
  ],
);
check("add disjoint (end)", new Intervals([[0, 4]]).add([8, 10]), [
  [0, 4],
  [8, 10],
]);
check("missing (none)", new Intervals([[1, 5]]), [], (obj) => obj.getMissing());
check(
  "missing (some)",
  new Intervals([
    [1, 5],
    [8, 10],
    [25, 25],
  ]),
  [
    [6, 7],
    [11, 24],
  ],
  (obj) => obj.getMissing(),
);


Thank you for the "What it does" Review Context,
that was lovely, very helpful.
I am slightly sad we're restricted to "dense" integers,
rather than ranges over the reals, but that's fine.
We'll roll with the Specification as originally stated.
long function
Yup, I agree, add() is Too Long.
I cannot read it on my monitor without vertical scrolling.
Though in its defense, it has some beautiful ASCII art
descriptions of the various cases.
Maybe extract that so it's above the function?
And then refer to numbered illustrations within the code?
That's just a stopgap.
The for loop seems like it wants to call a helper function --
that should be simple enough to extract,
and it would improve matters.
too permissive
There is a pre-condition that caller must obey.
    if (newInterval[0] > newInterval[1]) {
      newInterval.reverse();
    }

I feel that .reverse() call is too forgiving.
Caller messed up. They violated the
contract.
The appropriate thing to do is to throw a fatal error,
rather than paper over the caller's code defect.
automated test suite
Thank you, thank you for the unit tests!
Nicely done.

"The constructor's "init + for loop" seemed verbose. Wouldn't this suffice?": no, because this would not keep the intervals in order, which is required for the given implementation of add

"I am slightly sad we're restricted to "dense" integers, rather than ranges over the reals": the additional challenge with "dense integers" is that there is a concept of "adjacent". [[1, 2], [3, 5]] collapses to [[1, 5]] since 2 and 3 are adjacent to each other

"would not keep the intervals in order" Yikes! Well, clearly that's essential, sorry, I had no idea .slice() gets to re-order things. I'm accustomed to most datastructures offering a .copy() shallow copier. // "adjacent" Yeah, sure, I get that. You have adopted essentially the sql BETWEEN operator, using [a, b] closed intervals. I usually try to make time series and other continuous data follow a half-open [a, b) interval, because it has the desirable property that intervals compose in a natural way. (That would be $a \le t \lt b$.)

To clarify by "in order", I mean that add would not merge the intervals properly. Try using initial intervals of [[6, 6], [1, 2], [8, 10], [4, 5]] and add([1, 3]) (note: the [4, 5] and [6, 6] should also be combined to get [4, 6] in the constructor). You could also say it is part of the contract to return the intervals in sorted order by interval_start. array.slice() does not re-order the input

@FromTheStackAndBack , thank you for helping me see it. Quite right. I should have simply run a unit test, as I did just now. I withdraw the remark, and will update the post.
